# C++ Free Heap block 3da9e0 modified at 3daa08 after it was freed

Tags: c++, tree, heap-memory

I've seen the some solutions to this in this website but none of them solved my problem.
I'm implementing an n-children, unbalanced tree type and the add operation gives me an exception.
The code is as follows:

```
struct Node {
    // Just to initialize the parent node to zero, default constructor
    Node(Node *parent = 0) : m_parent(parent) {
    }

    Node *m_parent;
    vector<Node *> m_children;
    GameBoard m_currentBoard;
};
```

Where the error is happening:

```
Node *tempNode = 0;

// Going through each of them to create new nodes
for (unsigned int  i = 0; i < availableBoards.size() ; i++) {
    // Create a new node
    tempNode = new Node;
    tempNode->m_parent = curNode;
    tempNode->m_currentBoard.setBoard(availableBoards[i]);

    // This is the line when program crashes
    curNode->m_children.push_back(tempNode); 
}
```

I have also tried declaring the tempNode inside the loop but it didn't help either.

I've checked through the watch from Visual Studio, `curNode` isn't NULL nor the `tempNode`.

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: are you sure that `curNode` is valid (non null doesn't imply validity)? It seems it has been freed already

Comment: Yes I've double checked it, I pass it through the parameter. Only it's parent field is empty (root node) but the children vector is present with a size of 0.

Comment: "is present" doesn't imply validity. Freeing memory leaves the old data where it used to be so it can still look "valid" in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was destroying the object that was running the second code segment even before calling it. It was something like follows:

```
class A{
     int *getAsdf();
     int *asdf;
}

int main() {
    A *newObj = new A;
    delete newObj;
    newObj->getAsdf();
}
```

I don't have a single clue as to how a method is called from an object that was deleted before. Error happened inside a function like getAsdf and even the parameters were valid. Can some-one explain?

Comment: The parameter that wasn't valid was the this pointer.  Because this is a non-virtual function, the function call would be fine, but any dereference of this would be operating on invalid memory.  Any write to the this pointer (e.g. setting this->asdf to something) would likely corrupt the memory manager.

Comment: If i would tell you this is a badly written code, will it make you feel a bit better?